# How do I launch a specific view after user gets push notification?

Tags: ios, view, push-notification

I asked this question on the Apple forums and haven't yet received a response.

When I send a push notification to a user, and they click VIEW, it launches the app right?

What if I want to direct the user to a specific view? (something a little deeper than the normal app home screen) when they click VIEw.

Any help at all would be great.

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the view I would like to open directly has a BACK button. If I open straight to this view and the user preses BACK, what would happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate the view state starting in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.
So eg. if you have a navigationController, you have to push all viewcontroller, that were pushed on the time you left the application. You have to save that information on your own. E.g. in `applicationWillTerminate:`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sounds like a complicated approach, but if it's the only way then I guess I'll have to try it.

Comment: If your multitasking is enabled, your view will stay in the state it was. (until it is closed from the system) ALSO you could use a framework what does the work for you. Eg. Three20 or Nimbus.